# Google Sheet: COUNTA not recognizing blank cell generated by formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Live Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KcZiQLad_LDQ41rxRZsayY3jUQ7a35k1vFv3Y0tuSEk/edit?usp=sharing

I use `COUNTA` to calculate non-blank cells in a column. But if a blank cell is generated by a formula, `COUNTA` will regard it as a non-blank cell. From the sheet above you can see even if I import the formula generated blank cell to another cell ( so when you click on the cell the formula won't show and it looks like a genuine blank cell ), `COUNTA` will still see it as a non-blank cell.

Is there anyway to workaround this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `""`:

```
=IF(C1,1,)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

or you can do:

```
=IF(C1, 1, IF(,,))
```